# Storing files in the partition containing OS

Tags: partitioning

My hdd is partitioned into 220gigs n 250 gigs approx.Im able to store files on one of these partitions but I cant store any files on the other partition having the OS.The paste option never appears.I would like to use this space to store some files temporarily.Could you guys help me?If this question was asked previously Im extremely sorry.

Thanks in advance folks

Comment: You cannot just put anything anywhere since its the root directory. There is a specific folder to store specific stuffs. Like, You can always store your personal files under your home directory. I will not suggest you to use the system directories to store your personal files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could resize your home and root partition. The safest way would be to reinstall Ubuntu and set your root partition to something smaller. For most users 20Gb is plenty of space for a root partition. Leave your current home partition as is during the reinstall. Then you can expand your home partition into the newly freed up space.

Here is a useful article on modifing partitions with GParted without losing data: http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted

Comment: Thanq very much Greg

Comment: No worries mate

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permissions issue. You can see the permissions of a directory by right clicking properties or in terminal.

```
user@computer / $ ls -al
total 128
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Mar 19 17:09 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Mar 19 17:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 15 17:27 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Mar 30 07:47 boot
drwxr-xr-x  17 root root  4300 Apr  3 22:24 dev
drwxr-xr-x 164 root root 12288 Apr  4 12:31 etc...
```

In the example above all the directories are owned by root. Chown the directory you would like to store the files in replacing  with your username

```
$ sudo chown -R <your username> /path/to/dir
```

This will give you ownership of the directory so you can paste into it. The -R makes the change recursive so the ownership of sub directories are also changed.

Comment: It works magic.Kudos mate

Comment: Glad I could help mate.

Comment: Im sorry to bother you but I did change the permission of the var directory in the file system which resulted in ubuntu running on low graphics mode.How do I revert the  permission back to root?

Comment: $ sudo chown -R root:root /var

Comment: The root:root changes the owner and the group to root